# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'state'

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, runtime-error

This error pops up when I run the code I currently have.
Note : I did not write the code, I am simply trying to understand what's going on so that I can port it to a newer version of TuLiP.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vms5.py", line 270, in <module>
    states = [aut_state.state]
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'state'
```

Line 270 says :

```
states = [aut_state.state]
```

I tried looking for `state` and found this 
Line 249 :

```
state = dict(temp = Tmax, w = 0, h = 0, b = Bmax, a = 0, c = 0, nw = 0)
```

and `aut_state` at Lines 259 and 260

```
aut = createAut(aut_file = autfile, varnames = env_vars.keys() + sys_disc_vars.keys())
aut_state = aut.findNextAutState(current_aut_state=None, env_state=state)
```

---

Other terms with `aut`

Line 47 :

```
autfile = testfile+'.aut'
```

and Lines 223-234

```
# Check realizability
realizability = jtlvint.checkRealizability(smv_file=smvfile, spc_file=spcfile, \
                                           aut_file=autfile, verbose=3)

# Compute an automaton
jtlvint.computeStrategy(smv_file=smvfile, spc_file=spcfile, aut_file=autfile, \
                        priority_kind=3, verbose=3)
aut = automaton.Automaton(autfile, [], 3)
```

That's everything in the code that has `aut` related terms

---

If you want more info, please let me know

**EDIT**

I tried adding `print(aut_state)` before line 270 and got `-1` as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So aut is an int. Ints don't have an attribute called state. Whatever set the variable aut, set it with an int. Looks like an error code to me. Look at the code for findNextAutState - what does it return when there are no more AutStates? -1?

Probably a condition check missing.

Comment: You said `Look at the code for findNextAutState - what does it return when there are no more AutStates`. Can you please clarify what I should do ? The only line with findNextAutState is 260 mentioned above.

Comment: You need to step in to findeNextAutState() (and createAut()) using your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

from the traceback it is clear that `aut_state` is an integer, and integer cannot have any attribute called `state`. Your main Code problem  lies inside the `createAut()` which creates an aut object or inside the `findNextAutState()` function which returns `aut_state`.